# Build and execute C file in Vim using a shortcut

Tags: c, vim

I want to be able to build and execute the currently opened C file using a shortcut like in IDEs as I don't want to type a command every time I run.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I didn't try to do it. I just started with vim and I'm not familiar with it. I just wanted to configure basic C editing. Sorry about the question I just needed a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shell script that compiles and executes the file.

```
gcc file.c
./a.out
```

only works if you work with one file or #include, or you have to add the other files to the compiler.
As you probably work with a text editor, there are no other options than this, or doing it manually.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I wanted to automatically replace "file.c" with the currently opened file's name